# Localhost:8080 - This website is not available

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I tried Go Live in Visual Studio Code, I use JS to script. Whenever I try to launch it in my Chrome browser it opens and I get this message:

```
This website is not available. localhost connection denied.
Try this:

Checking access
Checking proxy or firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Tried to enter a image but I haven't been on this site for too long so I can't submit an image.. But I get a messag saying: The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused. And it tells me to check my internet connection/Check the proxy or firewall.

Comment: I tried editing and putting the exact messages I got when I launched it in Chrome. I am quite new to this so I am sorry for the misunderstanding. Is there anything more I need? The coding done in Visual Studio Code perhaps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Have you configured any proxy in your browser? Have you tried using another browser or a different profile of the same browser?